# How to secure an Azure role deployed to a virtual network?

Tags: security, azure

I am trying to place a web role behind a proxy. I have the proxy as web role (Proxy Role), and also another web role (Secured Role) that the proxy is to secure. The proxy is to accept incoming traffic, authenticate it and then either block it or pass it to the web role. The roles are deployed to a single virtual network.

One option is to only open *internal* endpoints on the Secured Role and deploy together with the Proxy Role which would have a *input* endpoint (as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh881877.aspx)). In this way, the Proxy Role is publicly accessible and the Secured Role is not. The Proxy Role however can pass authenticated traffic to an internal endpoint on the Secured Role.

The problems with this option are:

- Only works for roles.
- The roles have to be deployed together.
- The internal endpoints on the Secured Role aren't load balanced.

What initially seemed like another option is to have multiple subnets within the virtual network where these roles are deployed. The Proxy Role will be in one subnet and the Secured Role will be in another subnet. Then, access to the subnet where the Secured Role is placed would be secured with ACLs. The problem is that ACLs are only for virtual machines not roles as described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/10/29/set-by-step-setting-up-network-access-control-lists-acls-in-azure.aspx).

Yet another option is to have two virtual networks, one for the Proxy Role and one for the Secured Role. However, it isn't possible to ensure that the virtual network containing the secured role is only accessible by the virtual network containing the Proxy role. The virtual network gateway concepts seems to only be applicable to on-premise to cloud communication, not communication between virtual networks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Azure Service Bus?

> Keep your apps connected across private and public cloud environments
>   Windows Azure Service Bus provides the messaging channel for
>   connecting your cloud applications to your on-premises applications,
>   services and systems.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/messaging/

Comment: Thx, I looked into it, but I don't understand how to apply the Serivce Bus or Serivce Bus relay to address my scenario. I see how it can provide similar functionality, but not quite what I need.